# Google Calendar API v3 - get calendarId (email) from OAuth token object

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-client

How to get calendarId (user's email) from OAuth token object?

Details: Using the Google Javascript Client Library. 
After authorization, I need to get the user's email, which is the calendarId from the token object.

For Google Plus, the docs say that 'me' keyword can be used to refer to current authenticated user. It doesn't work for Calendar API. 
What should I do for calendar API?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem in the following way:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

The above link says how to retrieve the user information from the authToken by using the API: gapi.auth.setToken();

Comment: Links is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The attendee list of an event will contain addresses. Are you saying that you are unable to initialize the Calendar service?

Comment: No, I was meaning the Google calendar API that takes calendarId as an input parameter. But, I resolved it after reading this: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/